# How align left dedicatory

Tags: horizontal-alignment

my code is

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=30mm,right=20mm,top=25mm,bottom=30mm]{geometry}

\newenvironment{dedication}
  {\clearpage           % we want a new page
   \thispagestyle{empty}% no header and footer
   \vspace*{\stretch{1}}% some space at the top 
   \itshape             % the text is in italics
   \raggedleft          % flush to the right margin
  }
  {\par % end the paragraph
   \vspace{\stretch{3}} % space at bottom is three times that at the top
   \clearpage           % finish off the page
  }

\begin{document}
\begin{dedication}
Dedicated to google and wikipedia  
\end{dedication}
\end{document}
```

this is result:

[image]

Comment: You have specified `\raggedleft` which is the opposite of what you want.  Try `\raggedright`.

Comment: @barbarabeeton 
I want it to be placed on the right side of the page, and the content I want to be aligned to the left

Comment: To get a uniform indentation on the left, you can specify `\leftskip=`<dimen>`\parindent=0pt` where <dimen> is the amount of space you want on the left (e.g., `2cm`).  This is plain TeX notation, not LaTeX, but it should work.

Comment: @barbarabeeton the example i put in the figure in red letters

Comment: Yes, that's what I gave the code for.  It should be replace the `\raggedleft` in your code.

Comment: @barbarabeeton are you want public your answers please?, i am noob in latex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you post specifies `\raggedleft`, which is the opposite of what you want.  `\raggedright` is what you should be using.

You also want a uniform indentation on the left.  Replace the instruction `\raggedleft` in your code by the following:

```
\leftskip=2cm
\raggedright
\parindent=0pt
```

Replace the `2cm` in this code by the width of the indentation that you want.

This code is in "plain TeX" style, not LaTeX, but it should work with no problem, although some LaTeX users would prefer a LaTeX-specific formulation.

The reason I was trying to answer in comments is that I don't currently have the ability to test; I don't like to provide untested answers.

Comment: This answer did not work in my case, but adding the `\leftskip=2cm` option directly at the beginning of my paragraph instead of in the environment definition worked.